# find $r(t)$ s.t. $\alpha(t) = r(t)(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ have finite length on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: geometry

Question:

Consider the "spiral" $\alpha(t) = r(t)(\cos(t), \sin(t))$, where $r(t)$ is $C^1
$ and $0 <= r(t) <= 1$ for all  $t>=0$.
Characterize (in term of the existence of improper integral(s)) the function $r$ for which $\alpha$ has finite length on $[0,\infty)$

Thought:

I sticks at that I don't know how to take all the $r$ in consideration.I am thinking using Fourier series or Taylor's expansion to express arbitrary $r$.Is this strategy okay?

Comment: What have you tried so far? When asking a question on this forum you should give context and tell us about your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$ 
\alpha(t) = \bigl\langle r(t) \cos t,\, r(t) \sin t \bigr\rangle, 
$$
the derivative (velocity vector) is
$$ 
\alpha’(t) = \bigl\langle r’(t) \cos t - r(t) \sin t,\, 
r’(t) \sin t + r(t) \cos t \bigr\rangle, 
$$
and its magnitude (speed) is the square root of
$$
\bigl\lvert \alpha’(t) \bigr\rvert^{\,2} 
= r’(t)^2 + r(t)^2. 
$$
Thus the condition that must be satisfied in order for the length of the curve parametrized by $\alpha(t)$ on $[0, \infty)$ to be finite is that the improper integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \bigl\lvert \alpha’(t) \bigr\rvert \, dt 
= \int_0^\infty \!\! \sqrt{r’(t)^2 + r(t)^2} \, dt
$$
converges.